# Popup box if a negative number based from formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula, popupwindow, negative-number

I am trying to figure out a script that will popup a box if a number in column F goes negative. I think I may be running into an issue due to the negative number generating from a formula as opposed to someone manually typing it in. Here is the script I have been working with:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var editedCell = event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell();
  if(sheet=="Numbers"){
     if(editedCell.getColumn() == 6 && event.value==-0.1){   
        Browser.msgBox('It looks like there is a negative number in Column F.');
  }}}
```

I think it may have something to do with the 'editedcell' function but I am not 100%. Does anyone know of a better script that will popup a box even if a formula is generating a negative number (the value in column F will be a formula that may generate a negative)?

At this point, nothing happens with this code unless I manually type "-1" or some other negative in Column F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The event object returns the range of the cells you edited, not the ones edited by a script or formulae. As well as this, there are a few things you can do to fix or optimise your code.*

#### Code Fixes:

Firstly, you can change your conditional to optimise the script and only make calls when you need them - this I have done with a slightly different conditional order.

As well as this, rather than `event.range.getSheet().getActiveCell()` you need to specify the values of column F explicitly, and use the `getDisplayValues()` function as this will also pick up the values if the cell contains a formula:

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() != "Numbers") {
    return;
  }

  var values = sheet.getRange('F:F').getDisplayValues()
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] < 0) {
      Browser.msgBox('It looks like there is a negative number in Column F.');
      return;
    }
  }  
}
```

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Google Apps Script - Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much. I understand getting the values as opposed to the range in the active cell but one thing I am having issues understanding is why the sheet is referenced with "!= "Numbers")". What makes this different if you dont mind me asking? I am trying to learn to make these scripts more robust in future processing.

Comment: Glad to help! No worries - referencing with `!=` just means 'is not equal to' - the first thing the script does is check if the sheet being edited is the "Numbers" sheet, and if not it returns out of the function without doing anything else. That way you don't have to run additional code unless you really need to.